# MigraDoc and PDFsharp showing different documents when saving as PDF and image

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

When saving, the image has the right design but the PDF has the wrong text on it. Could you explain why the documents are different?

I'm also open to other solutions for saving a PDF of the whole document and the ability to print a selected page of a multi-page document.

thanks :)

EDIT: the image is showing the date ("24th May 2016") which is correct and what I want the PDF to show, but instead the PDF is showing "TEST TEST"

1

```
public static void pdf() {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string filename = "MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp.pdf";
        filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D").ToUpper() + ".pdf";
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

        SamplePage1(document);

        document.Save(filename);

        Process.Start(filename);

    }
```

2

```
    static void SamplePage1(PdfDocument document) {
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        gfx.MUH = PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;
        gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Default;

        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 13, XFontStyle.Bold);
        gfx.DrawString("TEST TEST", font, XBrushes.Black,
                        new XRect(100, 100, page.Width - 200, 300), XStringFormats.Center);

        Document doc = new Document();
        Section sec = doc.AddSection();
        Paragraph para = sec.AddParagraph();

        header("24th May 2016");

        DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
        docRenderer.PrepareDocument();

        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(5), XUnit.FromCentimeter(10), "12cm", para);
        PageInfo info = docRenderer.FormattedDocument.GetPageInfo(1);

        int dpi = 150;
        int dx, dy;
        if (info.Orientation == PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait) {
            dx = (int)(info.Width.Inch * dpi);
            dy = (int)(info.Height.Inch * dpi);
        } else {
            dx = (int)(info.Height.Inch * dpi);
            dy = (int)(info.Width.Inch * dpi);
        }

        Image image = new Bitmap(dx, dy, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        graphics.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        float scale = dpi / 72f;
        graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        gfx = XGraphics.FromGraphics(graphics, new XSize(info.Width.Point, info.Height.Point));
        docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, 1);
        gfx.Dispose();
        image.Save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        doc.BindToRenderer(docRenderer);
        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromCentimeter(5), XUnit.FromCentimeter(10), "12cm", para);
        Process.Start("mspaint", "test.png");         
    }
```

3

```
    public static void header(String date) {
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

        var dateIssued = firstPage.AddTextFrame();
        dateIssued.Height = "1.0cm";
        dateIssued.Width = "6.0cm";
        dateIssued.Left = "2.1cm";
        dateIssued.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
        dateIssued.Top = "3.55cm";
        dateIssued.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
        paragraph = dateIssued.AddParagraph(date);
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Showing images of what you get and explaining what is different from your expectations might help. An MCVE could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've added some clarification on what each format is showing. I'm trying to save the whole documents as a PDF and also individually print each PDF page, I'm currently printing each page via the image (awful solution but I cant find a better way)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for mixing MigraDoc and PDFsharp? Try to keep it simple and just use MigraDoc as intended. The code should draw "TEST TEST" in the PDF. You do not call the code that draws the header for the PDF case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, 1);` for the image only. This renders the header.

You do not call `docRenderer.RenderPage(gfx, 1);` for the PDF. So no date there, just the "TEST TEST" you draw earlier.

Comment: I've made some progress, instead of converting it to an image, I can just print the document using MigraDoc (I think?)  My only problem is getting printDocument.SelectedPage the source code on the MigraDoc website is using this.pagePreview.Page. How else can I get the selected page?

Comment: Don't set `SelectedPage` to print the whole document. There is only one page in it anyway, as I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your help!